# Get character level Confidance in tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract

I am using Pytesseract for OCR. But it looks like there is no option in the documentation to extract the confidence of ever character. I already have the Confidence of word but I want to know at which character the confidence is getting low.

So after research I came to know there is a function `tesserractExtractResult()` in the tesseract API which can give confidence of characters.

How can I use this function in Python?

Comment: Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162645/how-to-get-character-wise-confidence-in-tesseract-using-command-line?rq=1) - also no answers. It seems to require source code modification as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393555/character-confidence-for-tesseract-3-02-using-config-file) for an older version.

Comment: I added an answer for this (but tesseract not pytesseract) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162645/how-to-get-character-wise-confidence-in-tesseract-using-command-line?rq=1

Comment: Would you accept a tesseract answer or must it be pytesseract?

Answer (score 1):

Pytesseract calls Tesseract in the background as if launched in a terminal ([here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/18db82e66b1992812dc995a83271a82453f0dfc0/src/pytesseract.py#L223) in the source code), so you have at your disposition only what the shell command can do - and as far I know, you can't get character confidence.

I think that pyocr should be able to do so, but it is needed to add the function call (maybe in [tesseract_raw.py](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr/blob/master/src/pyocr/libtesseract/tesseract_raw.py)? ).

Also, more as a note: it seems that [python-tesseract](https://github.com/3togo/python-tesseract) and [pytess](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pytess/source) have at least some line in code referring to `tesseractExtractResult`, but last commits were respectively in 2015 and 2012.

Comment: Thanks for the Help. I was able to get it using tesserocr, But it seems all the characters were having a confidence of 98(approx), while the word confidene was 32. So not much of help here